# Call matlab from a Python virtual environment

Tags: python, matlab, virtualenv, osx-yosemite, matlab-engine

I can call MATLAB from my system python:

```
>>> import matlab.engine
>>>
```

but when I load a virtual environment, I now get a segfault:

```
>>> import matlab.engine
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I've run the [setup.py install instructions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html) for both system python and my virtual environment.

I expected questions [like this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/180518-why-does-matlab-engine-for-python-crash-when-using-a-non-system-default-version-of-python-on-mac), in which I have to set the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` explicitly would fix things, but I don't have that environment variable set when I run my system python.

What could be different between the two python implementations that would cause this segfault?

EDIT:
I'm using OS X Yosemite on a Late 2013 13" Macbook Pro. I'm using Python 2.7 from a freshly installed virtual environment (NOT a virtual machine).

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever make anything of this?

Comment: Nope - I just stopped trying to run Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
cd "matlabroot\extern\engines\python"
python setup.py install --prefix="installdir"
```

Where the `installdir` is my virtualenv, `matlabroot` the directory for the MatLab install.

Seems to work with my windows server, so far, so good.

Reference here:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-matlab-engine-api-for-python-in-nondefault-locations.html

Comment: Try to to format your answer/code to make it more legible.

Comment: Anyone get this to work on macOS? macOS seems to always want to use [`mwpython`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/python/mwpython.html) which I can't figure out how to get working with `venv`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the "`python setup.py install`" from `matlabroot\extern\engines\python` with my virtual environment active. Note that I did use `venv`.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully run Matlab 2019b through venv.
The command that I used: `sudo python3.7 setup.py install --prefix="/home/ubuntu/alexandros/vitrualEnv/py37`

You have to give the path to the full environment. In my case, it is  `/home/ubuntu/alexandros/vitrualEnv/py37/`. Inside the virtual environment, you will see

[image]

Then you have to go inside the lib and choose the version that you have installed. For instance, mine was 3.7 and that's why I have python3.7 instead of python3. You might have several python folders inside the lib folder like:

[image]

However, you have to use the one that is the main. Inside this folder you will see something similar to this:

[image]